# PHPExcel -> Converting Excels to array, parsing to DB -> Loop cycles more than it should

Tags: php, while-loop, phpexcel

I am developing a page where emails sent from myself are updating a webpage.

Steps:

`Email sent by me -> Website opened -> Script takes attachments from email -> script converts all .xls .xlsx to .csv, than parses to db for update`

However, my code runs through the `while` loop (labeled in code) 6-8 times when it should only be going once! Why?

Code:

```
<?php
    require_once('Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php'); 
    require('includes/email.php');

    $dir = 'excels/';

    // Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) { //*THIS WHILE LOOP*//
                //echo "yes";
                if(filetype($dir . $file) == 'dir') {
                    continue; }
                $ext = substr($file, -3);

        if($ext == 'xls') {

            $inputFileType = 'Excel5';
            $inputFileName = $dir . $file;
            $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
            $objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
            $loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetNames();

            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelReader, 'CSV');


            $objWriter->save(str_replace('.xls', '.csv', $inputFileName));

                $objWriter->save('abc.csv');
            $direct = "excels/" .$file;


            $files = fopen('abc.csv', 'r');

                while (($line = fgetcsv($files)) !== FALSE) {
                    $csv_array[] = array_combine(range(1, count($line)), array_values($line));
            }  
            $file2 = str_replace('.xls', '.csv', $file);
            $oldname = "excels/" .$file;
            $newname = "excels/archives/" .$file2;
            rename($oldname, $newname); 
            $delete = unlink($direct);

            //echo 'Your .xls file was uploaded successfully. Have a nice day.';


        } elseif($ext == 'csv'){
            $inputFileType = 'CSV';
            $inputFileName = $dir . $file;
            $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
            $objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
            $loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetNames();
            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelReader, 'CSV');

                $objWriter->save('abc.csv');

            $files = fopen('abc.csv', 'r');
            while (($line = fgetcsv($files)) !== FALSE) {
                    $csv_array[] = array_combine(range(1, count($line)), array_values($line));
            }   
            //echo 'Your .csv file was uploaded successfully. Have a nice day.';

        } elseif($ext == 'lsx') {
            $inputFileType = 'Excel2007';

            $inputFileName = $dir . $file;

            $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
            $objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

            $loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetNames();

            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelReader, 'CSV');

            $objWriter->save(str_replace('.xlsx', '.csv', $inputFileName));

                $objWriter->save('abc.csv');

            $files = fopen('abc.csv', 'r');

            while (($line = fgetcsv($files)) !== FALSE) {
                    $csv_array[] = array_combine(range(1, count($line)), array_values($line));
            }   
            //echo 'Your .xlsx file was uploaded successfully. Have a nice day.';       
        }

        else {
            //echo "This is not an accepted file type. Please save as either '*.csv' or '*.xls' and re-upload.";
        }
```

Comment: It runs 6-8 times on the same file on or different files ? How do you know it should run only once ?

Comment: It runs on the same file. it should stop because the while loop which opens `while (($line = fgetcsv($files)) !== FALSE) {` should only run through one `.csv` file once and stop when completed. However, it will restart itself on the same file. Why?